# jQuery UI and Firefox's Firequery plugin conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I use firequery plugin  as a tool to help me with jQuery based development.

I am evaluating the jQuery UI with Firefox's Firequery and Firebug plugins turned on. I see a ton of error messages when I visit the jQuery UI Tabs and Datepicker sample pages on the jQuery UI site with Firequery turned  :

```
missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error] ndow);
jquery.min.js (line 168)
jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error] e[d][1].apply(g.element,a)}},contains:...b.ui.isOverAxis(e,d,i)}})}})(jQuery);
jquery-ui.min.js (line 17)
jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error] $(document).ready(function() {
datepicker (line 2937)
jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error] jQuery(function(a){a.datepicker.region..."Don","Vry","Sat"],dayNamesMin:["So",
jquery....min.js (line 1)
$ is not defined
[Break On This Error] $(document).ready(function() {
demos.js (line 56)
$ is not defined
[Break On This Error] $.fn.themeswitcher = function(settings){
themeswitchertool (line 3)
$ is not defined
[Break On This Error] $(function() {
datepicker (line 273)
$ is not defined
[Break On This Error] $(document).ready(function() {
```

My question is whether these error messages are because of problems in jQuery UI code or Firequery plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of FireQuery. I don't have time to investigate the problem, but some people already reported that FireQuery interferes with some pages and breaks their jQuery code.

You may answer your question easily by disabling/uninstalling FireQuery and checking if the page has the same issues. You may use Firefox profiles to test it independently on your current settings.

Comment: I was able to determine that the problem  doe snot occus when the Firequery plugin in disabled. YOu can try tis yourself by viistong the JQUERY UI sortablc component with and without the Firequery plugin

Answer (score -1):

I have similar problems. My project is big and using a lot of JS libraries (38 different libs) with a lot of custom JS code. I found just problem in one:

jQuery UI library: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/complex.html
Test it with fireQuery, you will see bugs.

Problem was in variable definitions. jQuery also cause problems try:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ and drag div in sample